# Why can't some people store magnesium very well even though they seem to live healthy?

Tags: magnesium

Two examples are Dr. Mercola and George Newman.
https://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2017/11/26/fasting-powerful-metabolic-therapy.aspx

Dr. Mercola was taking 1 g of magnesium per day and yet his RBC magnesium was only 3.5 which was below average. His fasting insulin level was 2. Improved insulin sensitivity is supposed to help our cells store magnesium. 
https://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2016/11/30/how-to-lower-blood-pressure.aspx

Dr. Newman was able to treat his heart rhythm problems for at least two years by avoiding excessive exercise and taking magnesium. He took 5.5 g per day. Now he's taking 1.5 g per day. The shocking thing was that once he stopped taking it, within 48 hours, his AFib recurred, implying that he's excreting large amounts of magnesium.

It would seem like even if they ate foods grown in magnesium rich soil which seems like what Dr. Mercola was doing, they would still need to supplement.

Comment: Mercola = nonsense.

Comment: I'm sorry the articles were long and much of the content was unrelated. It did mention about Mg for a few paragraphs. After possibly years of high magnesium intake, we should expect high average RBC Mg levels but it's puzzling that the results said otherwise.

Comment: You shouldn't believe a word that Mercola has to say. His only objective is to get you to visit his web site so he can serve up ads and sell you stuff. https://www.quackwatch.org/11Ind/mercola.html

Comment: He did have links to studies such as those from Springer and Science Direct. Some also to blog articles. They weren't words that Mercola said. There's information about George Newman's condition that didn't include Mercola's words. http://www.afibbers.org/resources/journeys/Newman.pdf

Comment: Yes, Mercola is good as sprinkling his writings with legitimate sources to give it an air of credibility, but nevertheless he makes unsupported claims left and right. That article you linked to on afibbers.org was written by a layman with no medical background. He's not out to make money like Mercola is, but what's missing here is any credible evidence that the basis of your question has any validity; ie, that some people can't store magnesium. I doubt that's true.